# How to remove special characters from a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, trim

Could someone please help me to remove special characters from a string using javascript or Jquery.

**Note:**
I would like to remove only a specific set of special characters but not replacing it with any character. Below is the code i am trying. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
filename = filename.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%'":*?<>{}|]/g, '').replace(/\u201C/g, '').replace(/\u201D/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

**Sample string Name:**

Test5 & special~, #, %, & , ,, , , , , , , , “”

**Actual Result:**

(Test5 **space**  special-----------------------**spaces till here**)

**Expected Result:**

Test5 special

Comment: don't use blacklists, they will always let you down because of escaping, wierdo encoding, etc. use a char whitelist (with ranges).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with this function:

```
function removeSpecialChars(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?!\w|\s)./g, '')
    .replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
    .replace(/^(\s*)([\W\w]*)(\b\s*$)/g, '$2');
}
```

- 1st regex `/(?!\w|\s)./g` remove any character that is not a word or whitespace. `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- 2nd regex `/\s+/g` find any appearance of 1 or more whitespaces and replace it with one single white space
- 3rd regex `/^(\s*)([\W\w]*)(\b\s*$)/g` trim the string to remove any whitespace at the beginning or the end.

Comment: Thank you @Eloy. Your solution worked perfectly. I am also trying to replace some special characters that are unicode (.replace(/\u201C/g, '').replace(/\u201D/g, '')). Could you please let me know how to include in your regex.

Comment: @user545359 I edited the answer to address your comment and `dandavis` comment. He is right, it is better to use whitelist instead of blacklist. Please let me know if this work for you.